# selecting the first item of the spinner selecting the default value

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner in my app which is supposed to show a list of items. Initially it would be showing a default text and after selection has been made, all the item list will be seen in a drop down menu. The issue with the spinner is, when ever I am selecting the first item, the default value is getting selected. I know for some, it might be an easy question. However, if you are going to downvote, please do suggest an answer before doing that, because I have tried all possible solutions that I can. Below I am posting my code. Please have a look. Thanks in advance.

```
The spinner Adapter:

    public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> objects;
    String firstElement;
    boolean isFirstTime;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects, String defaultText) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
        this.isFirstTime = true;
        setDefaultText(defaultText);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(isFirstTime) {
            objects.set(0, firstElement);
            isFirstTime = false;
        }
        return getCustomDropdownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public void setDefaultText(String defaultText) {
        this.firstElement = objects.get(0);
        objects.set(0,defaultText);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
        label.setText(objects.get(position));

        return row;
    }
    public View getCustomDropdownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        CheckedTextView label = (CheckedTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        label.setText(objects.get(position));

        return row;
    }

}
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
In the mainactivity:

                            CustomSpinnerAdapter customSpinnerAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter((Context)MainActivity.this,
                                R.layout.spinner_row, dcuName, "Select One DCU");
                        dcuListScheduler.setAdapter(customSpinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: where is `setOnItemSelectedListener` method ?

Comment: you means that you have to prevent selection of first item on spinner?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement **[setOnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)** Method  .

```
dcuListScheduler.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
                {

                    if(dcuListScheduler.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select One DCU"))
                      {
                        // Select Default
                      }
                    else
                      {
                         // Select Other Options 
                      }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }

            });
```

Answer (score -1):

**Check position of selected item if it is grater then 0 then it will return true**

```
spinner_select_page.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    if (position>0)
                    {
                       return true;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: you can not return value when return type is void  hahaha  :))))))) @Hardikhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/8085378/hardik-kotadiya